# Rust code has a problem and say :no field `query` on type `std::result::Result<Config, &str>`

Tags: rust

I'm new in Rust, when I tried to run the code of "Listing 12-9: Returning a Result from Config::new" in "The Rust Programming Language", there were 3 mistakes that happened, but I have no idea to fix them.

Here is the message:

```js
{
    "resource": "/d:/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep/src/main.rs",
    "owner": "rust-file:///d%3A/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep",
    "code": "E0609",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "no field query on type std::result::Result<Config, &str>",
    "source": "rustc",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 41,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 46
}
{
    "resource": "/d:/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep/src/main.rs",
    "owner": "rust-file:///d%3A/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep",
    "code": "E0609",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "no field filename on type std::result::Result<Config, &str>",
    "source": "rustc",
    "startLineNumber": 11,
    "startColumn": 35,
    "endLineNumber": 11,
    "endColumn": 43
}
{
    "resource": "/d:/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep/src/main.rs",
    "owner": "rust-file:///d%3A/Document/Code/Rust/minigrep",
    "code": "E0609",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "no field filename on type std::result::Result<Config, &str>",
    "source": "rustc",
    "startLineNumber": 15,
    "startColumn": 46,
    "endLineNumber": 15,
    "endColumn": 54
}
```

And here is the code:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let config = Config::new(&args);

    println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    println!("In file {}", config.filename);
    // --snip--
    

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);
}

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

impl Config {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("not enough arguments");
        }

        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();
        
        Ok(Config{query,filename})
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `Config::new(&args)` returned `Err("not enough arguments")`? There wouldn't be a `query` or a `filename` field then.

Comment: So， what's the way the fix it？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config::new` looks like this:

```
fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str>
```

This means that it can fail. Thus, the `config` in `let config = Config::new(&args);` could be an `Err`or value.

Rust forces you to handle all possible variants of an enum like `Result`. For example, you can crash the program once it encounters an `Err` value:

```
let config = Config::new(&args).expect("Oh no, got an Err!");
```

Or handle the `Err` value manually:

```
let config = match(Config::new(&args)) {
    Ok(cfg) => cfg,
    Err(msg) => {
        println!("Error: {}", msg);
        return; // return from main
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanksa lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Config::new` returns a `Result<Config, &'static str>` not a `Config` so you need to deal with the `Result`. You can do so by unwrapping it by changing this line:

```rust
let config = Config::new(&args);
```

To this:

```rust
let config = Config::new(&args).unwrap();
```

Which will cause the program to panic if there's an error. Or you can propagate the error to the `main` function like this:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<(), &'static str> { // Result return type added here
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let config = Config::new(&args)?; // ? operator added here

    println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    println!("In file {}", config.filename);
    // --snip--

    let contents =
        fs::read_to_string(config.filename).expect("Something went wrong reading the file");

    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);
    
    Ok(()) // Ok(()) added here
}
```

The latter example is more idiomatic.